# Swift: understanding swift closure

Tags: swift, closures

I'm trying to understand closure in swift. I have the following swift implementation:

```
func whereToGo (ahead:Bool) -> (Int) -> Int{
    func goAhead(input:Int) ->Int{
        return input + 1 }
    func goBack(input:Int) ->Int{
        return input - 1 }
    return ahead ? goAhead : goBack
}

var stepsToHome = -10
let goHome = whereToGo(ahead: stepsToHome < 0)

while stepsToHome != 0 {
    print("steps to home: \(abs(stepsToHome))")
    stepsToHome = goHome(stepsToHome)
}
```

The output of the implementation is the following:

```
steps to home: 10
steps to home: 9
steps to home: 8
steps to home: 7
steps to home: 6
steps to home: 5
steps to home: 4
steps to home: 3
steps to home: 2
steps to home: 1
```

My question are the following:

1. Why is only executed this closure:

   ```
   func goAhead(input:Int) ->Int{
       return input + 1 }
   ```
2. Why on this line is not taking variable values:

   return ahead ? goAhead : goBack

I'll really appreciate your help to understand how swift closure work.

Comment: your question talks more about nested functions , which are special case of closure.

Comment: as apple docs says -: Nested functions are closures that have a name and can capture values from their enclosing function .https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html

Answer (score 5):

This line:

```
return ahead ? goAhead : goBack
```

is a more compact way of saying:

```
if ahead == true {
    return goAhead
} else {
    return goBack
}
```

So, since you have defined `goHome` as:

```
let goHome = whereToGo(ahead: stepsToHome < 0)
```

as long as `stepsToHome` is less than Zero, you are sending TRUE as the `ahead` parameter.

P.S. this really is unrelated to Swift Closures though...

Answer (score 4):

`whereToGo` is a function that returns another function based on the input parameter `ahead`. It returns a function that takes an `Int` and returns another `Int`: `(Int) -> Int`.

`whereToGo` declares 2 private functions inside it: `goAhead` and `goBack`, and these are the functions it returns one of them based on its input. These 2 functions are called [nested functions](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-ID178).

This line `ahead ? goAhead : goBack` uses the [ternary operator](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-ID71) to decide which function to return, when `true` it returns `goAhead`, else it returns `goBack`.

Here:

```
var stepsToHome = -10
let goHome = whereToGo(ahead: stepsToHome < 0)
```

You are calling `whereToGo` giving it `stepsToHome < 0` as an input parameter, which is a boolean value that evaluates to `true`. ==> `goHome` now refers to the nested `goAhead()` function ==> It will be called.

And you are iterating `while stepsToHome != 0` ==> the condition `stepsToHome < 0` will always be `true` ==> `goAhead()` function will always be called when you call `goHome(stepsToHome)`.